# How to "playback" what a user types - MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a need to create a textarea where a user would type text and the administrator should be able to playback the actions of the user at different speeds.

For example: A user types in - My name is Bob  and types in Dave, I need to capture these so that when an admin "plays" back, he should see what exactly the user typed in. Also, the admin should be able to play this at the same speed, 2x speed and 4x speed.

Is there a simple way of doing this other than having to capture every keystroke using javascript in the database and use those for playback? Thanks

Comment: That question has nothing to do with ASP but only with Javascript.

Comment: I agree with Kay, not ASP.NET, not MVC.

Comment: @kay and all the downvoters, this is a legitimate question. The OP understands the JavaScript approach but would like to find alternatives; no need to down vote.

Comment: @Omar: I did not vote the question down because it is a "bad question", but because of its intention: "the administrator should be able to playback the actions of the user".

Comment: @kay - Don't assume the intention is bad because it's keystroke recording. There's a vast number of safe/legal/non-evil application for key loggers: typing/learning programs, usability testing etc.

Comment: @kay - I guess it would depend on what the OP was trying to accomplish.  E.g., if the OP were trying to create a typing tutor website for a school or something like that. I'd personally wouldn't build a website to try to do that, but one could try and there'd be no malicious intention and probably no security concerns.

Comment: This is a lot like another question you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135492/textbox-to-capture-users-keyboard-strokes

Comment: @Omar and itsmatt: you two are right, I did not think of legitimate uses of key loggers.

Comment: Everyone, this is for a typing tutor site that as Omar noted. This is for a completely legit website! Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Might be an interesting approach to go with Silverlight for this - I know you specifically are talking about ASP.NET but a Silverlight app *might* provide for an easier (or at least different!) approach to the problem.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

This is largely a client-side problem - the server has no idea what is typed until the form is submitted when it gets everything in one go.

You could theoretically record every key stroke using JavaScript but it would be a monumental undertaking to make it work smoothly (reconstructing messages server-side, storing it in a useful way, writing a player, etc...)

Also, there is a security concern here - what happens if someone accidentally pastes a credit card number and then deletes it? For that matter, how are you going to handle copy/paste?

In summary, it's technically possible but it's non-trivial and has serious security/privacy issues.

If you insisted on trying this, the steps are:

- Capture every key stroke
- Transmit them with an exact time stamp to the server - either when the form's submitted or continuously using AJAX
- Record the keystrokes against some user/url/unique form Id in a database
- (Probably tie up whatever the form ACTUALLY does to this keystroke data)
- Write a page that can read all that keystroke information, load the page that it was entered on, inject some javascript/html to add a "player" on top of the usual page
- Repeat the keystrokes.

As you can see, this is a serious undertaking.

Comment: I don't care about copy pastes. If they do end up doing that, an admin should know as they cheated on their typing test.

Comment: @Dusty If it's for a specific textbox on a specific form, the solution becomes far simpler - Use a capture mechanism like the jQuery one @hunter has in his answer. Give each test a unique id - perhaps a guid. Use `$.post()` to send data (`key`+`timestamp`) back to the server via ajax. Make sure you capture the time in JS to eliminate network lag. Store it all in a database then use it as a "script" which you can play back using JS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to keep track of every key stroke. I would ajax post the current value of the textarea to an Action Method along with the current client time the keystroke took place. From here you could playback what the user was doing.

```
$("textarea").bind("keypress", function(e) {
    Post();
}

$(":text, textarea").bind("input paste", function(e) {
    Post();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't doing a ajax post for every keystroke pretty expensive?

Comment: @Dusty If you use AJAX, You'd probably want to buffer it - so every 100 keystrokes or after a period of inactivity, you'd send the data to the server. There's not really any advantage to using AJAX unless you want to be able to watch "Live" from another system. Failing that, posting the data with the form is just as useful but far more network-friendly. NB: I'm assuming nobody's going to be invested enough to try and manipulate the keystroke data...